# Sheduled tasks with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

The following code will invoke the `task()` method every second (although it takes longer than 1 second to run. I need to ensure that this method is invoked every second, no matter if it takes less or more than the invocation interval:

```py
import time
from threading import Thread

interval = 1
start, counter = time.time(), 0


def task():
    time.sleep(1.1) # 0.1s longer execution time than my interval
    print(time.time() - start)


while True:
    if (time.time() - start - interval * counter) > 0:
        Thread(target=task, daemon=True).start()
        counter += 1
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

This has worked fine for many months, but there must be a better way using asyncio...

#### My research and experiments so far:

- [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task)
- [`asyncio.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)
- [`asyncio.ensure_future()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future)

But I couldn't get this to work without every execution adding a delay of 0.1s in this case, but this is not tolerable in my case.

**If you need additional output etc, write a comment**

Comment: asyncio probably won’t help you here since the event loop only allows for one task to run at a time. cron is a much better tool for this than Python.

Comment: Are you aware that asyncio requires the code it executes to be async? I.e. it is not allowed to call any blocking function (such as `time.sleep()`), but only await async functions (such as `asyncio.sleep()`)? If so, then `create_task()` should work for you. Can you please edit the question to show your attempt with asyncio?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what `task` is actually doing? If it's CPU-bound, then asyncio probably won't help. But if it's I/O bound, then there is a solution with asyncio.